# What is $k((t))$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, notation, schemes, projective-schemes

Let $k$ be a field, what is the notation $k((t))$? I know that $k[[t]]$ is the ring of formal power series, but I've never seen $k((t))$. Sorry for such a stupid question.

For context, I'm supposed to be looking at a fixed morphism $\text{Spec }k((t))\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n_k$.

Comment: It's the ring of formal Laurent series

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Formal_Laurent_series

Comment: Anne and Alex have given you the right answer. I'll point out that, as noted in the Wikipedia article, $k((t))$ can be equivalently described as the field of fractions of $k[[t]]$ (when $k$ is a field).